# How do I use the Windows Magnification API in Python to invert the screen?

Tags: python, windows, screen

In Python, how can you invert the entire screen on a Windows PC without using keyboard shortcuts (as these are unreliable and can be turned off easily) using the ctypes module?

I've noticed it's possible using the [Windows Magnification API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/magapi/magapi-intro), but that is designed for C.  Using ctypes, I may be able to interface with the DLL, and invert the screen.  I can initialize it:

```py
from ctypes import *

class RECT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('left', c_long),
                ('top', c_long),
                ('right', c_long),
                ('bottom', c_long)]
magnification_api = CDLL('magnification.dll')

# declare types
BOOL = c_bool
FLOAT = c_float
INT = c_int
LPRECT = LPRECT = POINTER(RECT)
PBOOL = PBOOL = POINTER(c_bool)

# MagInitialize
magnification_api.MagInitialize.restype = BOOL

# MagUninitialize 
magnification_api.MagUninitialize.restype = BOOL

magnification_api.MagInitialize() # initialize the API

magnification_api.MagUninitialize() # uninitialize
```

How do I use the API to invert the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Windows Magnification API through the `ctypes` library:

```py
from ctypes import *

class RECT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('left', c_long),
                ('top', c_long),
                ('right', c_long),
                ('bottom', c_long)]
magnification_api = CDLL('magnification.dll')

# declare types
BOOL = c_bool
FLOAT = c_float
INT = c_int
LPRECT = LPRECT = POINTER(RECT)
PBOOL = PBOOL = POINTER(c_bool)
PMAGCOLOREFFECT = c_float * 25
MAGCOLOREFFECT = MAGCOLOREFFECT = POINTER(PMAGCOLOREFFECT)

# MagInitialize
magnification_api.MagInitialize.restype = BOOL

# MagUninitialize 
magnification_api.MagUninitialize.restype = BOOL

# MagSetFullscreenColorEffect
magnification_api.MagSetFullscreenColorEffect.restype = BOOL
magnification_api.MagSetFullscreenColorEffect.argtypes = (MAGCOLOREFFECT,)

magnification_api.MagInitialize() # initialize the API

magnification_api.MagSetFullscreenColorEffect((c_float * 25)(-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0,  0, 0,  0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)) # invert the screen

magnification_api.MagUninitialize() # use this to reset
```